# How to work each other page on top tabbar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[This is My Tab bar on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5RqM.png)

Hi teams,

I make some page with top tab bar and works many page on first page
it means you touch tab bar menu and change page.
I search many times but I can't find the solotion

First This is My tab bar Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../../constants.dart';

// We need stateful widget because we need to change some sate on our category
class Categorylist extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CategorylistState createState() => _CategorylistState();
}

class _CategorylistState extends State<Categorylist> {
  int selectedCategory = 0;
  List<String> categories = ["AB", "BC", "CD","DF","FG"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: kDefaultPadding / 2),
      height: 61,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: categories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildCategory(index, context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Padding buildCategory(int index, BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPadding),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            selectedCategory = index;
          });
        },
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              categories[index],
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.copyWith(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color: index == selectedCategory
                        ? kTextColor
                        : Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                  ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: kDefaultPadding / 2),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 6,
              width: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: index == selectedCategory
                    ? kSecondaryColor
                    : Colors.transparent,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It is just UI don't work anymore

and this is my home screen  which in body(include categories)

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(context),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Body(),
    );
  }




  AppBar buildAppBar(BuildContext context) {
      return AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: kDefaultPadding),
          icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/menu.svg"),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 200,
            alignment: Alignment(-0.4, 0.0),
            child: Text('JOA',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style:
              TextStyle(
                color: kTextColor,
                fontSize: 33,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPadding),
            icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/logon.svg"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WelcomeScreen()),
              );
            },
          ),

        ],
      );

  }
}
```

and last this is my body code

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // it enable scroll on small device
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Categorylist(),
          mainpage(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I work If i click AB to page 1
click BC to page 2?

Comment: it is only the navigation between the pages?

Comment: can you please add a more understanding screenshot? and explain more what is your desired output.